# How to create a query in laravel which fetch post and its user detail

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to fetch users Post and display their username & id below the post how can i create such query

Here is my Post Table

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  | id | user_id | title   | content   | status | time                |
  | 1  |   2     | example | Something | active | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 2  |   2     | example | Something | active | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 3  |   3     | example | Something | active | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 4  |   4     | example | Something | active | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 5  |   5     | example | Something | active | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

User table

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  | id |  name   |password |    img    | last_login          |
  | 1  |  User1  | example | Something | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 2  |  User2  | example | Something | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 3  |  User3  | example | Something | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 4  |  User4  | example | Something | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  | 5  |  User5  | example | Something | 2017-07-11 13:48:26 |
  ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I would like to fetch all post from database and fetch from users table - name,img,username etc...

Here is what my query looks like till now

```
$p1 = App\Models\Post::where('status', 'active')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Add a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) in your model and do `Post::with("user")->where...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... i used only JOIN because every post has a user.... 
you can refer this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

```
DB::table('post')
    ->select('post.*','user.id','user.name')
    ->join('user','user.id','=','post.user_id')
    ->get();
```

Try this for category just what you need to select just add it in select clause...

```
DB::table('post')
    ->select('post.*','user.id','user.name', 'category.*')
    ->join('user','user.id','=','post.user_id')
    ->join('category','post.id','=','category.post_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Is there any way that i can fetch category also? there is a category table which have id & post_id.

Answer (score 1):

By using laravel query builder

try like this

```
$result = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('post', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'post.user_id');
    })
    ->orderBy('users.id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```